# Charging on Free Tier of AWS RDS?

Tags: pricing, amazon-web-services

I´m trying to find out more on the possibilities with GeoClouding and PostGIS.
I was experimenting with AWS RDS feature with an Free Tier account, and now I´ve been charged a large amount of money. I might misunderstood something here. I´ve been charged for theese RDS-services (which i thought was inlcuded in the 750 free hours per month):

Amazon RDS Service for PostgreSQL ($0.910 per RDS Second Gen Extra Large Multi-AZ Instance hour (or partial hour) running PostgreSQL)

Amazon RDS Service Storage ($0.238 per IOPS-month of Multi-AZ Provisioned IOPS and $0.298 per GB-month of Multi-AZ Provisioned IOPS Storage)

These were tested in 2 regions: EU (Frankfurt) and US West (Oregon) Region.

I´ve only set up an empty  DB-instance,  and now they wanna charge me around 700 dollars.

So the question is: Did I misunderstood/didn´t understand the "contract" well enough or do I have any chance to avoid this? The bill hasn´t been charged from my card yet. It might be my own fault, but it´s jungle of texts and if you´re not from a country with english as your main language, then it´s confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The free usage tier for RDS does include 750 hours of usage per month, but it's for single-AZ Micro instance hours, not any of the larger instances. The micro instance normally costs $0.025/hour.
The included storage is single-AZ without provisioned IOPs.

The AWS web site is pretty clear on what is included in the free tier.

If you haven't tried contacting AWS support, you should, They may be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the info. That´s the parts i missed. I contacted AWS support as well. Learning costs...a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I had exact situation of 700$ and even after suspending my account I was being billed hourly as I had not terminated the RDS instances, but I called up aws customer support at 1 (888) 280-3321
and explained the scenario and it was an honest unintended mistake from my side as I had used extra large multi A Z RDS instance instead single with free tier.
Amazon was kind enough to wave off as gesture of good will and provided me video tutorials which would help me understand better.